# Replace #define X macro value with another one specified in compilation command

Tags: c, gcc, macros

Given the following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef STR
    #define STR "HELLO"
#endif

int main() {
    printf(STR "WORLD \n");
    return 0;
}
```

which says: if `STR` was not defined, then define it to be `"HELLO"`,
so the output will be

```
HELLO WORLD
```

How can I modify the value of `STR` when compiling using `gcc`?

I've tried

```sh
gcc -Wall program.c -DSTR="HI" -o program
```

but it didn't produce the expected output.

Comment: try `gcc -Wall program.c -DSTR=\"HI\" -o year`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, this is an answer

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Those backslashes were the problem, now it works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Comment: "didn't produce the expected output", it must have given you a compiler error, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in the form of:

```
-DSTR=\"MyString\"
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this is a shell issue. If the command would be `exec*()`ed for example the back shlashes wouldn't be necessary.