# How can I edit an executable during compiling, without changing its source?

Tags: c++, c, sed, makefile

I have to write a Makefile which compile the file year.c , and after this it will show the current year(2014) , not the previous one(2013).I have tried with sed function , but it works only if i use make run .

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef YEAR
 #define YEAR "2013"
#endif

int main(){
  printf("Hello world from " YEAR "\n");
  return 0;
}
```

And the Makefile:

```
year: year.c
        gcc year.c -o year

run:
        ./year | sed -e 's/3/4/g'
clean:
        rm year Makefile
```

Comment: assuming that your system clock is correct, you can use something like theTimeInSeconds = time(NULL);  tm = localtime(theTimeInSeconds); then use something like year = strfrtime().  strfrtime has the prototype: size_t strftime(char *str, size_t maxsize, const char *format, const struct tm *timeptr)  the format string would be: "%Y"  This would get you the current year each time the program is run.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26670985/971127

Comment: this is the second time we get this question.  It's a class assignment.  What is the Stack Overflow policy regarding class assignments?

Comment: @MarkGaleck: Stack Overflow policy is to consider every question by its own merits. Homework or not ought not be an issue, as long as the question is on-topic, clear, and well stated.

Comment: @Jongware  really? well, I am quite certain the professor in this class, does not wish the students get help, but work out the problems independently.  So, that means Stack Overflow policy goes against most likely wishes of a well-meaning professor?  I find that strange....

Comment: @Mark: SO policy is not involved with a question being homework or not. It's up to the integrity of the asker (but "write my assignment for me" questions usually get closed quickly). If the OP has a certain problem and can express it well, it's *definitely* on-topic for SO, neverminding the actual reasons *behind* asking it.

Comment: @Mark: Here is [the current consensus discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255477/please-clarify-the-policy-on-homework-questions). If you feel it's worth reviving the discussion based on new observations, developments, insights, or ideas, *do* post an answer to one of the existing Meta discussions (there already are a couple) or feel free to post a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define `YEAR` on the command line - the `#ifndef` will make sure that it doesn't get redefined:

```
gcc -DYEAR=\"2014\" -o year year.c
```

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, calculating the year directly in your program is a better solution, as stated in the comments.

In general, though, you'll need to make `run` a dependency of `year`. Here's a solution that uses an intermediate file, which doesn't overwrite `year.c`, but you can modify it to overwrite if you'd like:

`year.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef YEAR
 #define YEAR "2013"
#endif

int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello world from " YEAR "\n");
  return 0;
}
```

`Makefile`:

```
year: run
    gcc year_manip.c -o year

run:
    cat year.c | sed -e 's/3/4/g' > year_manip.c
```

Sample session:

```
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox/year$ ls
Makefile year.c
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox/year$ make
cat year.c | sed -e 's/3/4/g' > year_manip.c
gcc year_manip.c -o year
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox/year$ ./year
Hello world from 2014
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox/year$
```

Note that this solution means your program will always compile, i.e. your `run` target is never up-to-date. If you made it dependent on either `year.c` or `year_manip.c`, then when 2015 came around, it still wouldn't rebuild, which is probably not what you want. You could probably do something more complicated with `make`, to overcome this, if necessary.

For this particular problem, when the question is purely one of pre-`#define`ing an identifier with a value, the answer to the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670985/replace-define-x-macro-value-with-another-one-specified-in-compilation-command?lq=1) obviously gives a much simpler method which will work here. For more general code generation, using makefiles in this way can be useful.